# Why is neither /root/.bashrc nor /root/.profile executed after sudo -i?

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc, .profile

I have `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin"` in `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile` (nothing else in `/root/.profile`) and `/bin/bash` is the login shell for `root` in `/etc/passwd`. Yet invoking `sudo -i` (which according to `man sudo` starts a login shell and should run `~/.profile`) causes `/opt/local/bin` to be absent from `PATH` according to `echo $PATH`.

EDIT: invoking `bash` explicitly causes `/root/.bashrc` to be sourced.

The output of `sudo grep 'export PATH=' /root/.bashrc` is

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin" # MacPorts
```

`/etc/sudoers` (99 % sure I didn't change anything):

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: @kos all `export` statements involving `PATH` on the left hand side contain `$PATH`  on the right hand side. That shouldn't matter if I have the statement in both `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile`, right? Adding ``touch "/tmp/`date`"`` to `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile` and absense of any resulting files in `/tmp` indicates that both files aren't executed. A `sudo` bug?

Comment: Weird. I'm asking this in the chat.

Comment: I suspect your root shell is actually `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`. Can you please do `echo $SHELL` without sourcing the .bashrc file. Just do `sudo -i` and then echo command. Or you can do `grep 'root' /etc/passwd`

Comment: I'm not sure it matters in this case, but do you have an untouched `sudoers` or did you add something?

Comment: @kos Not (100 %) sure, I added the content above and don't see anything suspicious (`env_reset` shouldn't prevent the sourcing of `/root/.bashrc`).

Comment: @Serg Good idea! `echo $SHELL` prints `/bin/bash` and `grep 'root' /etc/passwd` `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`.

Comment: @KarlRichter one more question, do you have the following code in root's `.profile` :   `if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
`

Comment: The comment above meant to check if your `.bashrc` is sourced, because by default with `sudo -i` only `.profile` is sourced (or at least so says man page). I'm thinking that your `.profile` is sourced, but something is overriding PATH to default. Try setting the prompt to `PS1=' $ test ' ` just to check if the `.profile` is really sourced. If it is, move the setting for $PATH at the end. Try doing it without export as well, just `PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin"`

Comment: `/root/.profile` contains the `export PATH` statement only. Adding `PS1=' $ test ' ` indicates that `/root/.profile` isn't sourced when `sudo -i` is run. Omitting `export` and just declaring `PATH` doesn't help.

Comment: If your `PATH` is indeed overwritten sometime after `/root/.profile` has been sourced, `PS1` may be as well. So to test whether your `/root/.profile` is really sourced, I would use an entirely different statement, e.g., `echo "Sourcing .profile"`. Additionally, you could use similar statements in `/root/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and `/etc/profile`. This will show you exactly which files are sourced in which order when you issue `sudo -i`. Note that any of these files may source other files in turn. Classical printf-debugging should help you to narrow down the problem pretty fast. ;)

Comment: sudo will default to using *your* home directory.  Does this work with `sudo -Hi` or `sudo -His`? If not, how about `sudo su -`? That only uses sudo  to authenticate and otherwise just launches a root login shell, so if it doesn't work then your problem is not sudo.